# Using a laval nozzle as supersonic inlet - what happens at throat?

Tags: nozzle, supersonic

I am wondering what will happen, if I use the laval-nozzle , which normaly accelerates a fluid the other way round:

So what happens if I fly with my aircraft at Mach 2 and I collect all the air in my convergent - divergent nozzle ? I think there will be a big shock system which slows down to the fluid.

But: Is it still valid to have at the throat Mach=1 like for a rocket laval nozzle? So I will normaly have an oblique shock right before the throat?

Thank you for your thoughts
Lucas

Comment: It'll just choke and the shock forms right at the entrance.

Comment: Appears unrelated to space exploration.

Comment: @OrganicMarble might this apply to some air-breathing spacecraft like that British spacerocketplane [Skylon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skylon_(spacecraft))? For comparison, [Convergent-Divergent / De Laval Nozzle Dimensions](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/4337/12102) was well-received and has two answers, maybe this can benefit from and answer rather than having answering blocked so quickly?

Comment: As written, it's about an aircraft engine inlet.

Comment: This question may be more appropriate in the "aviation" community

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because  it belongs in "aviation"

Comment: @Woody that's not a close reason. We vote to close *if it's off-topic here*. "Belongs on" is not our call, that belongs to moderators when deciding where to migrate. See ["I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on Physics SE" is bad and here's why](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2866/12102)